# Does C++11 enforce pow(double, int) to use the slower pow(double, double)?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, std

In C++ 03, using e.g. `std::pow(double_val, 6)` was considerably faster than using `std::pow(double_val, 6.0)`.

This is no longer the case when compiling with C++11. Looking at the cmath header from gcc's libstdc++-4.8, one can see an explicit pow(double, int) is no longer present, this case is handled by the following template which promotes the int to a double:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Up>
inline typename __gnu_cxx::__promote_2<_Tp, _Up>::__type
pow(_Tp __x, _Up __y) {
  typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__promote_2<_Tp, _Up>::__type __type;
  return std::pow(__type(__x), __type(__y));
}
```

Is this behavior in the C++11 standard or could future libstdc++ implementations return to the faster method?

**Secondly**, if for standard or implementation reasons the faster behavior is no longer possible, what is the most portable way to achieve it again? I see a `power(...)` function in the gcc stdlibc++ under "ext/numeric", but this is marked as a **non-standard** SGI(rip) extension.

Comment: [Sounds right](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow): "If any argument has integral type, it is cast to `double`". Weird. And I can't find the reference in the standard...

Comment: @KerrekSB: I wonder what *effectively cast* means. Does that inhibit the implementation from offering other overloads? From a math point of view `x^5` and `x^5.0` are the same thing...(although they might not be in an implementation). I am not sure that the standard mandates that no extra overloads are provided if the results of both are the same.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I don't even know where the website takes that from. Can't find a reference for that...

Comment: @KerrekSB see [c.math]/3, and prepare c standard. Then it just add two new pow signatures that do not exists in c

Comment: related question: [Why was std::pow(double, int) removed from C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627030/why-was-stdpowdouble-int-removed-from-c11)

Comment: @KerrekSB There is, in **26.8 paragraph 11 [c.math]**. Had [some problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14295217/743214) with that myself already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, yes this behaviour is consistent with the C++11 standard (though not with C++03), which in section 26.8, paragraph 11 says:

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:
>
> 1. If any argument corresponding to a double parameter has type long double, then all arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to long double.
> 2. **Otherwise, if any argument corresponding to a double parameter has type double or an integer type, then all arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to double.**
> 3. Otherwise, all arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to float.

(In addition to the overloads for `float`-only, `double`-only and `long double`-only.)

So the implementation actually *has* to cast that integer argument into a `double` and I don't think there is a possibility for a conforming library to provide a faster `std::pow` for integer powers, apart from maybe checking the `double` argument for integrality (is that a word?) and using a special path in this case.

In order to provide a platform-independent faster way, the only thing that comes to my mind would be to write a custom wrapper that delegates to this non-standard `power` if it is present. Other than that I don't know how you could infuse that behaviour into `std::pow` again without writing your own implementation.

**EDIT:** Yet when looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5627278/743214) it is indeed possible for an implementation to still provide an optimized overload for integer powers as long as it behaves exactly like `std::pow(double(x), double(y))`. So there is a possiblity for an implementation to provide that faster version, yet I wouldn't count so much on this as you have done in C++03 (where it was IMHO even part of the standard, but I might be wrong).

Answer (score 2):

C provides just the `double pow(double, double)` overload (recall that C doesn't allow function overloading anyway). The C++11 standard (26.8/9) says that the following overloads are added (in addition to C's) to namespace `std`:

```
float pow(float, float);
long double pow(long double, long double);
```

<strike>Hence, `double pow(double, int)` is an extension rather than a standard function. Therefore an implementation might provide it or not.</strike>

**Edit** After Christian Rau comment and answer.

Now I believe the overload must be there. Hence, there should be a `double pow(double, int)` overload. However, this overload must (as he says in his answer) cast the `int` to a `double` and call `double pow(double, double)`.

Actually there are a lot of overloads. The easiest way to provide them is not as normal functions but as a template function exactly as the libstdc++ implementation shown in the OP.

See also [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2079) open issue where Howard Hinnant explains the details.

Finally the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627030/why-was-stdpowdouble-int-removed-from-c11) provided by Hulk is very relevant and Howard Hinnant (again) explains that there's almost no reason to provide an optimized overload that does anything different from casting the `int`to the `double`.

Comment: you also need to see which pow signatures are available. `double pow(double, double)` may no be an extension

Comment: @Hulk: The questions were: (1) "Is this behavior in the C++11 standard" (my answer is "yes"); (2) "could future libstdc++ implementations return to the faster method?" (my answer is "yes they can but that's not required)"; and (3) "what is the most portable way to achieve it again?" (I didn't answer because I don't know). Why it has been removed is another question that wasn't asked and for which I don't have an answer.

Comment: @BЈовић: `double pow(double, double)` is part of the C library that is refered in C++11 standard. It's declared in header `<cmath>` (see C++11 26.8/3, table 119). In addition, 26.8/8 says "In addition to the `double` versions of the math functions in `<cmath>`, C++ adds `float` and `long double` overloaded versions of these functions".

Comment: @CassioNeri You are right, I misread the question.

Comment: That isn't completely true. In 26.8 paragraph 11 the C++11 standard demands additional overloads, exactly to convert any integer into `double`.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I think you are right in the sense that the overload exists. However, I agree with Chistian Rau when he says (see his answer) that the implementation has to cast the `int` to a `double`. Hence, I don't see the point of the overload: Wouldn't an automatic promotion  `int` -> `double` do the same?

Comment: @CassioNeri *"Wouldn't an automatic promotion int -> double do the same?"* - Not neccessarily. What happens for `std::pow(1.0f, 1)`, it would take the `float`-version whereas it should take the `double`-version. And even worse, `std::pow(1, 1)` would be ambiguous.

Comment: @ChristianRau: First of all: I apologise for not realizing that you were the same person aswering the question and commenting on my post. Second. I agree with you: other calls (which are not `pow(double, int)`) would have to be treated sligth differently and reliying on automatic promotion wouldn't be enough. I've updated my answer and provided a link that might be useful. Thanks.

Comment: @CassioNeri Yet I updated my answer, since *Howard* stated in another answer of his, that it would still be possible to treat `pow(double, int)` differently, as long as it behaves *like* `pow(double, double(int))`. By the way, your link directs to the top of the *huge* issue list. Was it maybe [2086](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2086) you were referring to?

Comment: @ChristianRau: Oh dear! I've fixed the link but it's not the one you thought.